# A form having fields for personal info And also states, Cities fetching data from api... How to Make them work all togather without submitting form

Tags: forms, api, nested-forms, jquery-ajax

**Context**
I have created a form which is taking user data like their name, phone no, address...

For the address I'm using an api that is fetching states to a drop-down and also the cities after selecting a particular state...

I've done the state part because it doesn't require a submit request.

Now, the **problem** is that...
For fetching cities I tried jQuery and ajax but that requires a post request and I have other details for the form too so how do I make the cities drop down fetch the data of selected state without submitting the form (POST REQUEST)?
*Since nested form doesn't work in html* it's difficult for me to find the solution..

Please help me on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the fetch/ api call for the cities data on an event triggered by user over and the UI element which in your case should be the onChange event of the dropdown/select of the states.

```
const stateSelector = document.querySelector('.stateSelect');

stateSelector.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    getCitiesForState(e.target.value);
});

function getCitiesForState(state) {
    fetch(`http://exapleapitogetallcitiesinstate/${state}`, {
        "method": "GET",
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("cities data", data)
        // show cities dropdown, populate options in the select with the data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Instead of vanilla js you can use jquery

for event handling
https://api.jquery.com/change/#example-0

and fetching data with
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/